# Vue components is not passing prop value when dynamically loading components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am using vue 3 . i am trying to load the components based on components name i am assigning . I have 2 Child components.

1. CheckoutReceipt
2. ReceiptHistory

I am passing object as prop in both child component .My problem is when toggle to 2nd component i am not be able to get the prop value in my child component.On my first child component i am getting the receipt id but not on second component  its not getting it.

```
//PARENT COMPONET 

    <template>
    <div class="row p-p-0 p-m-0">
                <div class="col-md-5 ">
                    <component v-bind:is="componentName" :checkoutReceiptID="{receiptID: receiptID}" v-on:searchReceiptEvent="searchReceipt" ></component>
    
                </div>
     </div>
    </template>
    
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import {  Vue,Options } from 'vue-class-component';
    import SearchTransactions from "../../components/SearchTransactions.vue";
    import CheckoutReceipt from "../../components/CheckoutReceipt.vue";
    import ReceiptHistory from "../../components/ReceiptHistory.vue";
    
    @Options({
      components: {
          
          CheckoutReceipt,
          ReceiptHistory
       },
    })
    
    export default class Transactions extends Vue {
    
     private receiptID = '123456';
     private componentName = '';
    
     togglePage(pageName,receiptid)
        {
            if(pageName == 'history')
            {
                this.receiptID = receiptid;
                this.componentName = 'ReceiptHistory';
            }
    else
    {
                this.receiptID = receiptid;
                this.componentName = 'CheckoutReceipt';
    }
        }
    
    }
```

//CHILD COMPONENT

```
    <template>
      CHILD ID {{receiptID}}
    </template>
    
    <script lang="ts">
    import { Vue,Options } from "vue-class-component";
    import { camelCase } from "lodash";
    import moment from "moment";
    import Transaction from "../service/Transaction";
    
    @Options({
      components: {},
      props: {
        checkoutReceiptID: Object,
      },
      watch: {
        checkoutReceiptID(obj) {
          
          this.previewHistory(obj.receiptID);
        }
      }
    })
    
    
    export default class ReceiptHistory extends Vue {
    
      private receiptID;
    
      
    
      previewHistory(receiptID)
      {
          
           this.receiptID = receiptID;
       
      }
    
    }
```

My 2nd child component is same as my 1st child i just wannt to receive the receipt id in both components.

Comment: Probably caused by the typo: In the `else`-clause, you use `receiptID` instead of the `receiptid` argument.

Comment: actually its not the issue to make simple i removed other functions. coz that this happened let me fix

Comment: you have to use `v-bind="{receiptID: receiptID}"` to pass props to the dynamic components

Comment: i tried but on child component how i will call receiptID if i do v-bind="{receiptID: receiptID}"